# Group By by hiding a column - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table structure

Table1

```
ID  Hours    Qty      ProductID
1   2        1       100
1   3        5       200
2   6        6       100
2   2        2       200
```

If productid is (1,2,3) then i need  sum ( Qty * Hours),If productid in (200,300,400,500) then i need sum(qty).

I have written a code like this

```
select ID,case when productid in (1,2,3) then 
          SUM( qty * hrs) 
          when productid in (100,200,300) then   SUM( qty ) end result1

 from Prod group by id ,productid
```

but i don't want to group by productid,i would like to pass it in "IN clause".How to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `SUM()` outside of the `CASE WHEN` statement.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(case when productid in (1,2,3)       then qty * hrs
           when productid in (100,200,300) then qty
      end) result1
FROM
  Prod
GROUP BY
  ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all columns plus the result of your query, you can do this:

```
select p.*, aux.result
from Prod p
inner join (select ID,case when productid in (1,2,3) then SUM( qty * hrs) 
                           when productid in (100,200,300) then   SUM( qty )
                      end as result
            from Prod group by id ,productid) aux on aux.id = p.id
```